Unable to Select Points on Scatter Plot Using Charts (DGCharts)
I am trying to create a scatter plot with two different datasets (entries and entries2) in a ScatterChartView. While I can successfully interact with and select points from the entries dataset, I'm facing issues with accurately selecting points from entries2. When tapping on points from entries2, the selection often highlights incorrect or unintended points instead.
I've tried messing around with maxHighlightDistance and granularity to no avail. How can I ensure that the touch input accurately selects the intended data points from entries2?
My code is below:
import SwiftUI
import DGCharts

struct ScatterPlotView: View {
    var body: some View {
        SimpleScatterPlotView()
    }
}
 
struct SimpleScatterPlotView: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    // The data for the chart
    var entries: [ChartDataEntry] = [
        ChartDataEntry(x: 1.0, y: 2.0),
        ChartDataEntry(x: 2.0, y: 3.0),
        ChartDataEntry(x: 3.0, y: 5.0),
        ChartDataEntry(x: 4.0, y: 4.0),
        ChartDataEntry(x: 5.0, y: 6.0)
    ]
    
    var entries2: [ChartDataEntry] = [
        ChartDataEntry(x: 104, y: 714),
        ChartDataEntry(x: 123, y: 666),
        ChartDataEntry(x: 104, y: 715),
        ChartDataEntry(x: 109, y: 601),
        ChartDataEntry(x: 119, y: 665),
        ChartDataEntry(x: 116, y: 602),
        ChartDataEntry(x: 113, y: 664)
    ]
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ScatterChartView {
        let chartView = ScatterChartView()
        chartView.noDataText = "No data available"
        chartView.doubleTapToZoomEnabled = false

        let dataSet1 = ScatterChartDataSet(entries: entries, label: "Data 1")
        dataSet1.colors = [NSUIColor.blue]
        dataSet1.setScatterShape(.circle)

        let dataSet2 = ScatterChartDataSet(entries: entries2, label: "Data 2")
        dataSet2.colors = [NSUIColor.red]
        dataSet2.setScatterShape(.circle)

        let data = ScatterChartData(dataSets: [dataSet1, dataSet2])
        chartView.data = data

        return chartView
    }

    
    // Update the view in response to data changes
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: ScatterChartView, context: Context) {

    }
}

